Google maps does not change location
tengo este codigo:
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 } // Posición inicial provisional
        });

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: 'Ubicación'
                });

                map.setCenter(pos);

                map.addListener('click', function (event) {
                    placeMarker(event.latLng);
                });

                document.getElementById('latitude').innerText = pos.lat;
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerText = pos.lng;

            }, function () {
                handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // El navegador no soporta Geolocalización
            handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
        }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, pos) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ map: map });
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    }

    function placeMarker(location) {
        // Mueve el marcador a la nueva ubicación
        marker.setPosition(location);
        // Puedes obtener las coordenadas y hacer algo con ellas
        var lat = location.lat();
        var lng = location.lng();

        console.log('Latitudlng');

        // Opcional: Actualizar campos ocultos en un formulario ASP.NET para guardar la ubicación
        document.getElementById('latitude').innerText = lat;
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerText = lng;
    }

Tengo estas dos etiquetas:
<p>Latitud: <span id="latitude"></span></p>
<p>Longitud: <span id="longitude"></span></p>

En google maps se ve que el cursor si arrastra la ubicacion de un lado para otro (tengo entendido que esto es el Market), pero no se actualizand las etiquetas (los dos span que pongo en el codigo de arriba) ni las variables y tampoco muestra nada en la consola web (estoy usando Edge si alguno cree que es mejor usar otro navegador que me lo diga)-
Estoy usando ASP.net aunque aun no agregue ninguna linea de codigo en la parte del codigo C# asi que no publico ningun codigo al respecto.
Hay algo que tenga que agregar o me estoy olvidando de algo?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Y el mapa lo muestra?

si lo muestra sin problemas.
